# How to input an specific amount of lines from a text file into an array and repeat the action untill all lines are used

Tags: python, list

I have a text file with 89000 lines.
What I want is to input 100 names at the time into a function, but do this for the entire file.

So you could say:

Load 100 lines

Do something with those lines

Sleep

Repeat

Before this I only used `for every line in file` but I have no clue how to do; `for every 100 lines in file` and actually use those lines to read information.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), you can get selected items from an iterable:

```
with open('/path/to/file') as f:
    while True:
        lines = list(itertools.islice(f, 100))  # similar to `f[0:100]`
        if not lines:
            break
        # process lines
```

Comment: so this creates 890 "lists"?
How does it know how to use which "list" ?

Comment: @Snowlav, It creates a list with 100 items (or less for the last time if there's not enough items) 890 times in a loop.

Comment: @Snowlav, I don't understand the second part of the comment.

Comment: any idea on how to delete `/n` with printing?

Comment: @Snowlav, If you mean removing trail newlines: `[line.rstrip(\n) for line in lines]`